# GPS getting turn offf in service with LocationManager

Tags: java, android, gps, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

we have developed C.R.M. software which provides location tracking functionality in background . to achieve that functionality i have used foreground service for android OREO or above version of android .

we are trying to get current location of user using `LocationMangager` and have attached `onlocationchage` listener . we are successfully getting data in service , and than storing those data in SQLite .

twist is that when we kill the application or put application in the background service runs fine but location manager doesn't gets longitude and latitude after a while may be 2 - 3 minutes . we also checked that . if service is running in the background or its getting killed but  service is running in the background and printing log in the logcat. we have put `CounteDownTimer` to print log in `LogCat` . we also tried to keep application open , not killed , not even in background . it happens same , LocationManger was not getting latitude and longitude after a while . application was running in our phone on main screen .

here is the things we tried : -

- i have tried GPS provider ( not working after a while )
- i have tried Network provider ( not working after a while )
- i have tried passive provider ( not working after a while )
- i have tried google fused location but it is not even getting location data .
- i have put `WakeLock` in service so that CPU does not go into idle mode (tried partial and full wake lock)

Note : -

- i am demanding location for given interval and for given distance . i have tried in our office and also out side of office but we are not getting data after a while . i am sure that given distance is getting covered .

thank you in advance and i can not show my code reason is that our company does not allow to post Company code in any platform . sorry .....

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to run the service in the foreground. As part of that, you'll need to request the permission in your manifest, along with a couple of others things. I followed [this example](https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/432d3b72b8c058f220416958b444274ddd186abd/LocationUpdatesForegroundService) recently to solve a similar issue.